# Get public or private key from address with C-lightning

Tags: lightning-network, segregated-witness, core-lightning

I'm studying Lightning network and I use c-lightning.
I can Get a new address with `newaddr` method, but I can't find private key.
My address is `bcrt1qmckts70jsq2u5886lgcq2yn7xjmp97t09zlrg`, how can I retrieve it's public key?
Where Can I find it's private key?

```
$ bitcoin-cli validateaddress bcrt1qmckts70jsq2u5886lgcq2yn7xjmp97t09zlrgj                                                              │
{                                                                                                                                       │
  "isvalid": true,                                                                                                                      │
  "address": "bcrt1qmckts70jsq2u5886lgcq2yn7xjmp97t09zlrgj",                                                                            │
  "scriptPubKey": "0014de2cb879f28015ca1cfafa3005127e34b612f96f",                                                                       │
  "isscript": false,                                                                                                                    │
  "iswitness": true,                                                                                                                    │
  "witness_version": 0,                                                                                                                 │
  "witness_program": "de2cb879f28015ca1cfafa3005127e34b612f96f"                                                                         │
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`lightningd` doesn't offer simple RPC commands to dump keys.

If you really need to access the keys the simplest way would be to derive them directly from the `hsm_secret`.

Keys for onchain transactions (since you mentioned `newaddr`. The other derivations are more involved) are derived using BIP32 unhardened derivation from `m/0/0`.
The root seed is derived from the `hsm_secret` with :

```
root_seed = hkdf_sha256(hsm_secret, salt=NULL, info="bip32 seed")
```

There exist tools such as the [`hsmtools`](https://github.com/ElementsProject/lightning/blob/master/tools/hsmtool.c) *(which currently only derive keys for the commitment transactions but might be extended in the furure)* or jb55's [`clightning-dumpkeys`](https://github.com/jb55/clightning-dumpkeys/) which take care of the derivation for you.